# What are the advantages of a rxjs Observable over a DOM event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, rxjs, reactive-programming

I have been studying rxjs and reactive programming but there is something I didn't quite understand yet.
For instance, I want to get the result of a `keyup` event on a simple input, map it, and set the map result as another `div` content:

```
const root = $('#root'),
      input = root.find('#some-input'),
      result = root.find('#result');
```

Using rxjs, I can do:

```
const keyupObs = fromEvent(input, 'keyup');
const mapper = keyupObs.pipe(
    map(e => $(e.target)),
    tap(t => result.html(t.val()))
).subscribe(t => console.log(t));
```

Using a jquery driven event, I can write:

```
input.on('keyup', e => result.html($(e.currentTarget).val()));
```

Which is less code and for a begginer like me does not seem to differ that much from what I wrote using rxjs.
So what are the main advantages of using rxjs, and why should I use it over DOM driven events(in this case using jQuery)?

Comment: I guess despite all benefits of Rx (combining, transforming, controlling mechanism) using jQuery code is absolutely normal if you don't have to deal with complex events logic. It will keep your bundle size smaller as well. But if I have to do simple autocomplete input I bring RxJS In the project without doubts. It's going to be just 5 lines of code and perfectly working component with debounce, checking minimal line length etc.

Answer (score 1):

1. the main benefit here is that you can use rxjs operators if you expose the DOM event as an observable, ie filtering or switching or combining or debouncing is easier.
2. you have finer control over when to start and stop listening via subscribe and unsubscribe. You also have an easier time preventing memory leaks so long as you unsubscribe properly.
3. a layer of abstraction over the DOM is helpful for a number of reasons. such as, if the context of your app ever changes, your app is more portable, or if the DOM interface ever changes, rx should be doing their best to keep you insulated from it. you're also better insulated from cross browser issues. Though in theory jquery should be handling this as well, but in my experience jquery is operating under the assumption that you’re in a browser like environment whereas rxjs is less so.

Answer (score 1):

Take the definition of observable:

> Observables are lazy Push collections of multiple values.

This in itself, does not mean much. In your case, the event mechanism suits your needs and simulates the stream.

What if you wanted to:

1. Merge values with another stream?
2. Map and modify in a complicated way the output?
3. Have asynchronous streams that promises don't support?
4. Cache the output after the first value?
5. Use it across components and services?

Event observable provides the least value on its own but if you want to consume and combine with others, the observable will provide a plethora of operators to play with.